# avdmanager create Error: Package path is not valid

Tags: android, linux, debian, android-virtual-device

I'm using Debian 10 + Oracle JDK-11 + the latest Android command line tools as at 12/04/2023 (commandlinetools-linux-9477386_latest.zip).

I've installed the command line tools like so;

```
      1. Unzip
         : cd /usr/local
         : sudo mkdir android
         : cd android
         : sudo unzip ~/Downloads/commandlinetools-linux-9477386_latest.zip
         : cd cmdline-tools
         : sudo mkdir latest
         : sudo mv * latest

      2. Install all the tools required
         : sudo latest/bin/sdkmanager "emulator" "platform-tools" "platforms;android-31" "build-tools;31.0.0"
```

Now when I go to install my AVD I get the following error;

```
$ cd /usr/local/android/cmdline-tools/lastest/bin
$ ./avdmanager create avd -n device -k "system-images;android-31;google_apis_playstore;arm64-v8a"  
[=======================================] 100% Fetch remote repository...       
Error: Package path is not valid. Valid system image paths are:
null
```

If I list my packages I can see the android-31 there;

```
$ cd /usr/local/android/cmdline-tools/lastest/bin
$ ./sdkmanager  --list_installed
[=======================================] 100% Fetch remote repository...       
Installed packages:
  Path               | Version | Description                | Location          
  -------            | ------- | -------                    | -------           
  build-tools;31.0.0 | 31.0.0  | Android SDK Build-Tools 31 | build-tools/31.0.0
```

I have the following environment variables setup;

```
PATH=/home/map7/.cask/bin:/home/map7/.cask/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/android/sdk/tools/:/usr/local/android/sdk/platform-tools/:/usr/lib/jvm/adoptopenjdk-8-hotspot-amd64/bin:/usr/local/android/sdk/tools/:/usr/local/android/sdk/platform-tools/:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11/bin:/usr/local/android/cmdline-tools/latest/bin
ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/android
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/home/map7/.android
```